# Graphing using r and points (pch)

Tags: r, graphing

What happens to my R-code? I don't want to see the bar graph and I want to see only the plotting characters (pch):

```
plot(Graphdata$Sites,ylim=c(-1,2.5), xlab="sites",
          ylab="density frequency",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$A,pch=1,col="blue",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$B,pch=2,col="green",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$C,pch=3,col="red",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$D,pch=4,col="orange",lwd=2)
legend("topright",
       legend=c("A","B","C","D"),
       col=c("red","blue","green","orange"),lwd=2)
```

[image]

Part of my data looks like:

```
     Sites     A     B     C     D
    1     A 2.052 2.268 1.828 1.474
    2     B 0.549 0.664 0.621 1.921
    3     C 0.391 0.482 0.400 0.382
    4     D 0.510 0.636 0.497 0.476
    5     A 0.214 0.239 0.215 0.211
    6     B 1.016 1.362 0.978 0.876
......................................
.....................................
```

and I want the legend according to pch and not in the form of line.

Comment: The meaning of the `Sites` column in your data is a little confusing. If the values in the column `A` are from site A, what information does the `Site` column provide? When I look at your data I can't tell if the value 0.549 is supposed to be from site A, or site B (row) or something else entirely.

Comment: If the first argument to `plot` is a factor, then the default plot type is a bar graph. If you want a different sort of plot you need to review the plotting functions and specify the code differently.

Comment: A, B, C, D, A, B are under sites @Joran

Answer (score 1):

The barplot is happening because you're plotting the factor of your `Sites` column. To only plot the points:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#plots 6 categorical variables
Graphadata.m = melt(t(Graphdata[-1]))
ggplot(Graphadata.m,aes(Var2,value,group=Var2)) + geom_point() + ylim(-1,2.5)
```

If you want it to plot 4 categorical variables instead:

```
Graphdata.1 = t(Graphdata[-1])
colnames(Graphdata.1) = c("A","B","C","D","A","B")
Graphdata.m = melt(Graphdata.1)
ggplot(Graphdata.m,aes(Var2,value,group=Var2)) + geom_point() + ylim(-1,2.5)
```

**EDIT:**
In base R:

```
plot(1,xlim=c(1,4),ylim=c(-1,2.5), xlab="sites",ylab="density frequency",lwd=2,type="n",xaxt = 'n')
axis(1,at=c(1,2,3,4),tick=T,labels=c("A","B","C","D"))
points(Graphdata$A,pch=1,col="blue",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$B,pch=1,col="green",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$C,pch=1,col="red",lwd=2)
points(Graphdata$D,pch=1,col="orange",lwd=2)
```

Comment: I didn't mean I only want to plot the point @desc. I only want the pch and I don't want the bar graph there. Tell me just how to get rid of the bar plot and that is my problem??

Comment: @Stackuser, and your issue (as `42` noted above) is that you're first plot is for a factor, which is defaulting to a barplot. So you can use `ggplot` as noted in the answer here, or if your set on using base plot then see the edit above.